# Can we limit APScheduler to run 100 times only?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html) to run a python method in every 5 minutes. It's working perfectly. I need to limit the scheduled job iteration to 100. After the 100 iteration it should close the process. I have checked the reference document but I am unable to find any option which provide this feature. We have option to control number of job instance but not the max iteration. Does anyone has idea about that?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job():
    print "Decorated job"

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', minutes=5)
scheduler.start()
```

OR
if I get the scheduled job iteration count then I can also remove the running job from code itself like below.

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', minutes=5, id='my_job_id')

#iterationCount ??

if (iterationCount = 100 ):
    scheduler.remove_job('my_job_id')
    exit(0)
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html?highlight=apscheduler.triggers) the `interval` trigger allows setting the time range for the job:

> You can use `start_date` and `end_date` to limit the total time in
>   which the schedule runs.
>
> ```
> sched.add_job(job_function, 'interval', hours=2, start_date='2010-10-10 09:30:00', end_date='2014-06-15 11:00:00')
> ```

This is not exactly what you want, but it at least allows to set the end date which you can easily compute yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Leon for your response. Yes definitely it will allow me to control the job iteration.